# How do I mix Non-Tensorflow code with Tensorflow ops?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use a third party library (neural renderer) in my code alongside Tensorflow. This library has a function which I would like to run between Tensorflow executions. However, whenever I feed a placeholder into the function, it just gives me this problem:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'transpose'
```

How do I combine a Tensorflow session and a non-Tensorflow function? For example, how do I do something like this:

```
input = not_tensorflow(foo, bar)
op1 = tf.assign(var, input)
sess.run(op1, feed_dict={foo:stuff})
```

I thought I would make foo a simple Placeholder, but apparently that doesn't work.

Comment: Tensorflow version? What is originally needed by the library (what type)? Have you tried with version `2.0` (which has eager execution and could be easily casted to `numpy` and other data types)?

Comment: @SzymonMaszke It's tensorflow version 1.14.0 Is eager execution a requirement for this?